# How to set up a separate D-pad or remote control for Android TV Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, d-pad

I wanted to know how to set up a separate D-pad or remote control for the Android TV emulator I have created on Android Studio. I tried the default 'Directional Pad' on the Emulator options, but I am wanting a separate d-pad like in another frame which is also an emulator. Also, the TV emulator and the remote control should be connected to each other for easier navigation and control.